# Is it hard to get an article published in a journal as an undergraduate?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate

I'm an undergrad and I would like to publish in a research journal, specifically, ones about chemical pedagogy.

Is it hard to get an article published in a journal?

Are there any other venues which may be easier - i.e. do you know of any say magazines on chemical pedagogy or aimed toward chemistry educators? I'd imagine that the standards for publication in a magazine are lower than in a scientific journal.

Any advice for a beginner at writing and publishing?

Comment: Do you have an advisor at your university? They would be the appropriate person to ask this.

Comment: Related: [Assume an undergrad has something worth publishing: how might (s)he get it published](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/assume-an-undergrad-has-something-worth-publishing-how-might-she-get-it-publi)

Comment: Thanks. I like to assume that what I have is worth publishing ;). We'll see how well that assumption holds up.

Comment: _Is it hard to get an article published in a journal?_ — Well, that depends on the article, doesn't it?

Comment: Most articles outline new/original research using new/original data and some sort of experiment and statistics. Did you do anything of the sort, or is it more of a review?

Comment: @JeffE: ...and the journal. :-)

Comment: @Dissenter: "I like to assume [it] is worth publishing." From what I have seen on (mathematics) forums, many amateurs are overconfindent on the interest of the work. As others pointed, you should ask a professor to evaluate your work. Journals are amazingly specialized these days and the experience of a professor would help a lot to link you to the good journal. Another good test is the bibliography: try to write it on your own and compare to profesional articles. Most articles I mentioned above had a very poor bibliography (if any): Wikipedia is not enough for a research level article.

Comment: @Dissenter The main journal for chemical pedagogy is *[J. Chem. Ed.](http://pubs.acs.org/journal/jceda8) and while they do accept publications from undergrads (and I'm sure would be happy to review it), as others have said, you may want help of a faculty member to submit. I expect you could find some on Chem.SE.

Answer (score 6):

I would imagine that your best bet is to talk to a faculty member about it. Find a faculty member who is also interested in the topic. They can probably give you good advice on this and may even be interested in co-authoring the paper with you (which is probably more realistic as an undergrad), and honestly going this route wouldn't be too bad for you since your name would then be associated with an expert on the subject, giving you more credibility.

One thing I've learned in college is that if you have an idea, talking to a faculty member about it can get you a *lot* of opportunities. And if you talk to someone and they can't help you, they can almost always refer you to someone else who can be of help.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the journal. You might want to try publishing in your university's undergraduate journal if you don't have backing from a faculty member.

[For an example of a university-specific undergraduate journal, [click here](http://thurj.org/).]

Comment: "your university's undergraduate journal" What's that?

Comment: How is backing from a faculty member relevant?

Comment: Having support from a faculty member is relevant because, even if you are a good writer, writing a journal article is a difficult skill to learn on your own. The faculty member can help you learn this skill.

Comment: example of undergraduate journal: http://thurj.org/

Comment: @David: That's a good answer, thanks.  (I was a graduate student at Harvard not so terribly long ago, but the journal did not exist then.)  I think that if you're not fortunate enough to go to Harvard it is less than likely that your university has an undergraduate journal of its own...but this may no longer be true X years from now.  I took the liberty of editing the link into your answer -- I hope you don't mind.  Doing so also allowed me to reverse my downvote.

Comment: @Pete: The Harvard of the South also has its own undergraduate journal: http://juro.uga.edu

Comment: @TK Duke has an undergraduate journal?  :) Anyway, I am a little embarrassed by not knowing about your link, but I would be much more embarrassed if I had made the comment in 2010.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask questions "Is it hard to get an article published in a journal?", about journals and in general "Any advice for a beginner at writing and publishing?", etc. then  it is very unlikely you will publish something in a reputable journal, based only on a few lines of advice via Internet.

However:

- try looking at student's conferences; very often there are great places to share undergraduate work, and learn how to present results (via posters, talks, sometimes - conference proceedings),
- ask someone from your university to look at your work, and guide you through the first publication (a lot of work, but worth it); but since it's chemistry you do it in someone's lab, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is hard to publish in a peer reviewed journal.

If it were easy anybody and everybody would do it. That should not prevent you from trying.

Typically a magazine is easier to publish in. The real question you need to ask yourself is "Who is my target audience?" The general public? Or experts in the field? If the general public, a magazine might be the best choice.